# ngModel is not a property of "input" in angular (importing FormsModules does not work)

Tags: angular

I have tried barely everything but ngModel seems to not be working in the `component.html` file.

I have the following html inside a form

```
<input [ngModel]="username" type="text" name="username" [placeholder]="'INPUT_USERNAME_HINT' | translate"/>
```

And I get the error described in the title.

I have tried `([ngModel])="username"`, `[(ngModel)]="username"`, `(ngModel)="username"`, `[ngModel]="username"` but non work (first and last ones crash and the ngModel simply does not recognize the property of the component).

I have the following in my app.module

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

(...)

@NgModule({
    declarations: [ AppComponent ],
    imports: [
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        HttpModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
            loader: {
                provide: TranslateLoader,
                useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
                deps: [Http]
            }
        }),
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule
    ],
    providers: [SERVICE_PROVIDERS],
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
```

I even tried the BrowserForms I can't remember now but that also did not work.

I really can't find what could be wrong and I really need to know

I'm using the following angular seed btw https://github.com/TeamMaestro/angular-native-seed

Thank you for your help

Comment: check this https://angular.io/guide/forms

Comment: I am wondering if you have all packages at the same version

Comment: @Robert I'm sorry but this does not help me

Comment: Please add reproduction

Comment: I have downloaded the angular-native-seed, run npm install and run ng serve - open. In the home.component.html i dumped your <input [(ngModel)]=... etc. and added <p>{{username}}</p>. Everything works fine. It seems that either your component is not registered to your module or your packages are not loaded / installed properly. The bananabox notation is the correct one [(ngModel)]

Comment: In which module is this component where you used the input ?

Comment: where the actual component? where you use username.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It should be `[(ngModel)]`

```
<input [(ngModel)]="username" type="text" name="username" [placeholder]="'INPUT_USERNAME_HINT' | translate"/>
```